# getting compilation error with gxt

Tags: gxt

I am getting following error while compiling the code. I want to use auto-complete combo box. Also I have created model.

```
[INFO]  extends java.lang.Object
[INFO]  implements : com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.data.ModelData, java.io.Serializable
[INFO] /*   fields   */
[INFO] protected [unresolved] boolean allowNestedValues
[INFO] protected [unresolved] Unresolved type com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.data.RpcMap map
[INFO] /*   methods   */
[INFO] public void <init>() 
[INFO] [unresolved] public void <init>(Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object>) 
[INFO] public X get(java.lang.String) 
[INFO] public X get(java.lang.String, X)
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't you forgotten to add the gxt libs in your module.gwt.xml

```
<inherits name="com.extjs.gxt.ui.GXT" />
<inherits name="com.extjs.gxt.themes.Themes" />
<inherits name="com.extjs.gxt.charts.Chart" />
```